# How can I use Django template language inside another one?

Tags: django

I'm trying to use a static image with a file name decided by forloop in Django template.

```
{% for items in dictionary %}
    <tr>
    {% for records in items %}
        {% if forloop.counter == 2 %} 
            <td><img src="{% static '{{ records }}.png' %}"></td>
        {% else %}
            <td>{{ records }}</td>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

It turned out '{{ records }}.png' part didn't work as I intended.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a variable as

```
# Add this at the top of your page after the extends part
{% static "images" as baseUrl %}
```

replace your img part with this

```
<img src="{{baseUrl}}/{{records}}.png" alt="">
```

This should work

Comment: `{% static "images" as baseUrl %}` understand the logic over here, this code evaluates to the path of your images directory inside the images folder. Suppose your project name is `mysite` then that will become `mysite/static/images`. If your images are stored inside images folder then this will work perfectly fine but if you have any app/folder inside that image directory then you need to explicitly specify that too in your `img` tag

Comment: What do I put inside " " when I want to use default static dirs?

Comment: Nothing keep it empty

Comment: then it becomes "/static//image.jpg" resulting in error